# OpenGL video frame fitting

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, kinect, sdl-2

I am working on a project where I have to project the data from a camera with a resolution of 640x480 on a 4K screen in portrait mode.

The camera is the Kinect V1 but I will switch to version 2 with a better resolution (1920x1080).

My question is how to change the scale of a texture to display in order to get a correct result.
For the moment, I have managed to display on the entire screen but the image is flattened in width. The ideal would be to keep the proportionality and cut an X width on each side of the image.

I am using SDL with OpenGL, here is the concerned part of the code:

```
// window creation
auto window = SDL_CreateWindow("Imagine",
                                   x,
                                   y,
                                   0,
                                   0,
                                   SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP | SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI | SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS);

// GL initialization and texture creation
void SdlNuitrackRenderHandler::initTexture(int width, int height)
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glOrtho(0, _width, _height, 0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    glGenTextures(1, &_textureID);

    width = power2(width);
    height = power2(height);

    if (_textureBuffer != 0)
        delete[] _textureBuffer;

    _textureBuffer = new uint8_t[width * height * 3];
    memset(_textureBuffer, 0, sizeof(uint8_t) * width * height * 3);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureID);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // Set texture coordinates [0, 1] and vertexes position
    {
        _textureCoords[0] = (float) _width / width;
        _textureCoords[1] = (float) _height / height;
        _textureCoords[2] = (float) _width / width;
        _textureCoords[3] = 0.0;
        _textureCoords[4] = 0.0;
        _textureCoords[5] = 0.0;
        _textureCoords[6] = 0.0;
        _textureCoords[7] = (float) _height / height;

        _vertexes[0] = _width;
        _vertexes[1] = _height;
        _vertexes[2] = _width;
        _vertexes[3] = 0.0;
        _vertexes[4] = 0.0;
        _vertexes[5] = 0.0;
        _vertexes[6] = 0.0;
        _vertexes[7] = _height;
    }

// Texture rendering
// Render prepared background texture
void SdlNuitrackRenderHandler::renderTexture()
{
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureID);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, _width, _height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, _textureBuffer);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, _vertexes);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, _textureCoords);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Comment: How did you come up with that code in the first place? I see so many issues with this that it really won't fit into a stackoverflow answer.

Comment: This code is partially (without SDL but glut) provided by NuiTrack wiki : http://download.3divi.com/Nuitrack/doc/nuitrack_gl_sample_2src_2main_8cpp-example.html

Comment: That wiki code has already a couple of weird constructs, and it is using out-dated OpenGL which has been deprecated since a _decade_ by now. So I wouldn't start from that. However, OpenGL is a complex, and (from this point of view) quite low-level rendering API. It will require learning a lot of things before you can actually understand the solution to your issue - and this is something which can't be provided on StackOverflow.

Comment: I'll manage, thanks anyway.

Comment: You say  the 4k display is in portrait mode? That's a bit unconventional. You also say you'll later be displaying 1920x1080 content on it. If it is in portrait mode, you'll be  using a very small portion of the screen when you switch to the HD feed. It'll be like watching  an HD movie on your phone  with  the phone held in portrait mode. You'll have a small rectangle surrounded by huge black bars above and below. Is  that the intent or have I misunderstood?

Comment: I explain the project to you, I think it will be clearer for you.
In fact, I develop (for school purposes) a connected mirror integrating augmented reality. So, the idea is to display the user on the screen to simulate a real mirror.

Comment: Ah, OK. That  does make more sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I agree with what was written in the comments about this being out-dated OpenGL code, the issue has nothing to do with OpenGL at its heart. You want to draw 1 rectangle with the correct aspect ratio inside another rectangle that has a different aspect ratio. You simply need to know where to place the vertices.

Typically with the `TEXTURE_2D` texture target, you want your texture coordinates to be 0-1 in both directions, unless you plan to crop the input image. There was a time when textures had to have a width and height that were a power of 2. That hasn't been the case in a very long time. So remove these 2 lines:

```
width = power2(width);
height = power2(height);
```

So the first thing is to set those properly:

```
    _textureCoords[0] = 1.0;
    _textureCoords[1] = 1.0;
    _textureCoords[2] = 1.0;
    _textureCoords[3] = 0.0;
    _textureCoords[4] = 0.0;
    _textureCoords[5] = 0.0;
    _textureCoords[6] = 0.0;
    _textureCoords[7] = 1.0;
```

(Consequently, that code is *really* hard to read and will be a pain to maintain. You should make the texture coordinates (and vertex coordinates) be a `struct` with an `x` and `y` value so it makes sense. Right now it's not obvious that it's 4 sets of 2D coordinates that are (max, max), (max, min), (min, min), (min, max). But I digress.)

Next, to figure out the texture coordinates, you need to know whether the video is going to be scaled to fit the width or the height. To do this, you can figure out

```
double widthScaleRatio = displayWidth / imageWidth; // <- using this scale will guarantee the width of the new image is the same as the display's width, but might crop the height
double heightScaleRatio = displayHeight / imageHeight; // <- using this scale will guarantee the height of the new image is the same as the display's height but might crop the width
double  scale = 1.0;
// If scaling by the widthScaleRatio makes the height too big, use the heightScaleRatio
// Otherwise use the widthScaleRatio
if (imageHeight * widthScaleRatio > displayHeight)
{
    scale = heightScaleRatio;
}
else
{
    scale = widthScaleRatio;
}
```

Now scale you width and height by the `scale`:

```
double newWidth  = imageWidth * scale;
double newHeight = imageHeight * scale;
```

and set your vertices based on that:

```
    _vertexes[0] = newWidth;
    _vertexes[1] = newHeight;
    _vertexes[2] = newWidth;
    _vertexes[3] = 0.0;
    _vertexes[4] = 0.0;
    _vertexes[5] = 0.0;
    _vertexes[6] = 0.0;
    _vertexes[7] = newHeight;
```

And the same caveat applies to making this code easier to read as with the texture coordinates.

**EDIT:** Here's  a simple program to show how it works:

```
int main(){
    double  displayWidth    = 2160;
    double  displayHeight   = 4096;
    double  imageWidth  =  640;
    double  imageHeight = 480;
    double widthScaleRatio = displayWidth / imageWidth; // <- using this scale will guarantee the width of the new image is the same as the display's width, but might crop the height
    double heightScaleRatio = displayHeight / imageHeight; // <- using this scale will guarantee the height of the new image is the same as the display's height but might crop the width
    double  scale = 1.0;
    // If scaling by the widthScaleRatio makes the height too big, use the heightScaleRatio
    // Otherwise use the widthScaleRatio
    if (imageHeight * widthScaleRatio > displayHeight)
    {
        scale = heightScaleRatio;
    }
    else
    {
        scale = widthScaleRatio;
    }

    double newWidth  = imageWidth * scale;
    double newHeight = imageHeight * scale;

    std::cout << "New size = (" << newWidth << ", " << newHeight  << ")\n";
}
```

When I run it, I get:

> New size = (2160, 1620)

Comment: The first part of this answer actually breaks the texcoords because in the given code, the image is embedded into an texture with power-of-two-dimensions (which of course is itself a relict from pre-historic GL).

Comment: Thank user1118321 for your code, I'll study it.
@derhass In the new versions of OpenGL the two-dimensional textures are no longer used, is that it?

Comment: @RiehlAlexandre: no, 2D textures are still 2D. the power-of-two requirement has been removed ~15 years ago. But that is only a minor detail.

Comment: Okay, thank you both. I will document myself to update the code with the latest version of openGL.

Comment: @user1118321 I tried your code, the image is completely zoomed in. Maybe I misspelled the dimensions: 
displayWidth = 2160;
displayHeight = 4096;
imageWidth = 640;
imageHeight = 480; newWidth and newHeight are respectively 1920 and 1440

Comment: When I run it, I get 2160x1620  for  `newWidth` and `newHeight`. I'll show what I did in a minute.

Comment: @user111832 Now I get the same value than you but the problem is the same. When the width and height is 640 and 480, the image cover all the display but the image is flattened in width. The width should be larger and the image truncated to keep the proportionality. The problem is that with your code the image is zoomed in, my hand takes the whole screen for example. The problem of the aspect ratio could comes from this function no : glOrtho(0, _width, _height, 0, -1.0, 1.0); ?

Comment: If you want to fill the screen, then you need to pass `displayWidth` and `displayHeight`  to `glOrtho()` to get  a 1:1 mapping of coordinates to pixels in x and y.

Comment: @user1118321 Thanks a lot, it works as expected. Now I will just try to keep the display's height and crop the image in width.

Comment: In that case, you should switch the `if` condition to be `<=` and it should do what  you need.

Comment: @user1118321 Thanks, it works but the width is too large (average 5K pixels). I have to center the texture because currently only the right part of the texture is visible.

Comment: There are 3 ways you can handle scaling: 1) stretch (distort) the image, 2)fit the image into the display in one dimension with unused space in the other dimension, 3) fill the display, which will crop the image. You had 1 originally and didn't like it. I showed you 2 and you said it wasn't right because it didn't fill the display. Then you tried 3 because it's the only other option. It crops. You just  need to decide which one you want.

Comment: @user1118321 Yes you're right, in my case the best solution would be the third. Crop the image in width